# How to make usb drive write only and block read access, execute only and block read access

Tags: windows, registry, gpo

I know we can make use of Local GPO/ registry to deny read/write/execute access.

But when we deny read access even write and execute is disabled.

I need write and execute to be available while read access being disabled.

Please provide some suggestions...